Preventing Widowed Captions in minted Listings
I use minted extensively in my documents. In order to associate a caption I create a block of LaTeX code like this:
\begingroup
\begin{minted}{latex}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}ll}
\textit{Col 1} & \textit{Col 2} \\
this is a test 00 & test 01 \\
this is a test 10 & test 11 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minted}
\captionof{listing}{Tabular Preamble Extension via array Package}
\endgroup

However, this sometimes produces a widowed caption like this:
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{Tex Gyre Adventor}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[skip=2pt]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=8pt}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\parskip 4pt
\parindent 0pt

\section{Tabular Environment Preamble Extension}

This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.

This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.

This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.

This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.

This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.

This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.

This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.

This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.
This is a test of filler text.

Using the array package allows the tabular environment's
preamble to be extended. For example, 

\begingroup
\begin{minted}{latex}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}ll}
\textit{Col 1} & \textit{Col 2} \\
this is a test 00 & test 01 \\
this is a test 10 & test 11 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minted}
\captionof{listing}{Tabular Preamble Extension via array Package}
\endgroup

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}ll}
\textit{Col 1} & \textit{Col 2} \\
this is a test 00 & test 01 \\
this is a test 10 & test 11 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


I've found a way that avoids such widowed captions by inserting \widowpenalty=10000 into the group:
\begingroup
\begin{minted}{latex}
\widowpenalty=10000%
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}ll}
\textit{Col 1} & \textit{Col 2} \\
this is a test 00 & test 01 \\
this is a test 10 & test 11 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minted}
\captionof{listing}{Tabular Preamble Extension via array Package}
\endgroup

This has the effect of forcing at least one line of the preceding minted environment before the caption.
However, I'm not sure if this covers all the possibilities, or even exactly how it works.
My question is this: Will this solution prevent widowed captions in all scenarios, and if not, can a comprehensive solution be suggested?
I'd also appreciate an explanation of why the existing solution works.

Do you have listings with page breaks?

Yes. If you modify the group using the \windowpenalty you will see a page break of the listing.

The question is, do you want to allow page breaks in listings (except for just before the caption) or are all your listings less than one page long and are you ok with them floating around (including their caption)? In that case you can use the approach with \begin{listing}\begin{minted}...\end{minted}\caption{...}\end{listing} as described in the minted manual on page 10/11.

I do want to allow page breaks in listings, and I am not ok with them floating around. But thanks for the clarifying questions.
